# I spilled some powder detergent on the floor

Tags: word-usage

I know that "spill" will sound natural with "liquid detergent". But will it sound natural with "powder detergent"?

> I spilled some detergent on the floor. (It is a "powder detergent", not a liquid one)

Is the use of "spill" natural here?

Comment: Yep! And you can even ["spill beans"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans)

Comment: But spill the beans is an idiom used in relation to revealing secrets...

Comment: @shin yep, that is what the link I included says. I thought it would also be useful to point out that even less "fluid" things than powders can be considered "spilled". The list of (non-idiomatic) usages can even include M&M's, grapes, or pebbles

Comment: I think it's a pragmatic requirement that anything which ***spills*** must be doing so under the influence of gravity, but that doesn't mean it has to be a ***liquid***. For example, carbon dioxide is heaver than air, so in high concentrations it tends to sink rather than diffuse into the atmosphere. As in [*That fateful day in 1969, **carbon dioxide spilled out** of the Mauna Ulu vent, and the windless conditions permitted the gas to collect in a pool along the trail that Don and I walked.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="1969+carbon+dioxide+spilled+out")

Comment: @katatahito Or *my lazy handwriting **spilled** into the margins of the page.*

Comment: Many people prefer **powdered** detergent.  (That’s an adjective plus a noun.).  But “powder detergent” (a compound, noun-noun) is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Combining answers from the comments section :

Yes powder laundry detergent can be considered "spilled"

In general "spill" should be used:

> a. For substances that move fluidly (liquids, gasses, powder, pebbles) if they move outside of a container, general moving under the influence of gravity (i.e. toward the floor\ground /etc.)
>
> b. It can also be used figuratively when semi-continuous things "move" outside of their intended constraints
>
> > My handwriting spilled into the margins
> >
> > The wedding planning spilled into the next month, past the intended deadline
>
> c. There is also the idiom of "spilling the beans" to mean telling a secret to someone. Similar in meaning to "letting the cat out of the bag."